# Java Cant read or write object to file

Tags: java, object, serialization

There is this method `klasOpslaan(Klas deKlas)`. I need to write `deKlas` to an object. Afterwards I need to read it with method `klasInladen`. I am getting an error `writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: week5.practicum4.Klas` although I implemented `Serializeable`. I did note that when writing my object it makes the object but doesn't write to it. I did implement everything but StackOverflow wont let me post it.

```
public class KlasManager implements Serializable {

    public void klasOpslaan(Klas deKlas) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Sam\\Documents\\Java School\\klas.obj");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        System.out.println("Klas opgeslassgen");

        oos.writeObject(deKlas);

        oos.close();

    }


    public Klas klasInladen() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Sam\\Documents\\Java School\\klas.obj");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        Klas deKlas = (Klas) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();

        return deKlas;

    }
}
```

edit: needed `Serializeable` in other classes, not in this one.

Comment: did you actually implement `Serializable` in your `Klas` class?

Comment: Does all the fields of `Klas`implement `Serializable` as well?

Comment: `KlassManager` doesn't need to implement `Serializable`, `Klass` does.

Comment: Can you post the code for the `Klas` class please?

Comment: @nhouser9 Thank you very much! I thought `Serializeable` was only needed in the class where I loaded everything in.

Comment: @SamVruggink No problem, happy to help!